# Why does this example not cause Dirty Reads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm playing with Kafka Streams a bit and while investigating `WordCountProcessorDemo` I realized there must have been part of the picture that i'm missing. Namely, how does the library guarantee that no dirty read could happen in the code below:

```java
@Override
public void process(final String dummy, final String line) {
    final String[] words = line.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split(" ");

    for (final String word : words) {
        final Integer oldValue = this.kvStore.get(word);

        if (oldValue == null) {
            this.kvStore.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            this.kvStore.put(word, oldValue + 1);
        }
    }

    context.commit();
}
```

As far as I undestand the matter, after firing `kvStore.get(..)` the state might get changed by another StreamProcessor instance, living on other machine consuming different partition. Therefore, since we performed a dirty read, the state will become inconsistent.

Does Kafka Streams deal somehow with such situation ?

Answer (score 1):

> the state might get changed by another StreamProcessor instance

Not really. The state is sharded and thus each `Processor` has it's own exclusive share of the overall state.

Comment: But then, in the end we need to have results/state (word counts) aggregated from across all the processors, right ? Is there some thread in Kafka streams that reads all state shards and aggregates them to produce output topic ?

Comment: Data should be partitioned by key before you do the counting.